# Combine cells into single cell with sub-list

Tags: google-sheets

I am just wondering if there is a formula in which I can combine multiple columns into single cell with sublist on each. I have already attached a sample sheet with sample output below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MB4aGpwvz_okI1A_yjqPahK1gqwk_01euV7KPAdYuBM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(FILTER(A2:A500,A2:A500<>""),CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B2:B500,A2:A500<>""),CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&CHAR(9))),CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&"no sublist","")))
```

### Explanation

The formula's innermost `SUBSTITUTE` replaces each line break in column B with a line break and a tab. `CONCAT` then combines that with each result in column A. Note that due to the `FILTER` functions, for both column A and column B, only rows where there is a value in column A will be included.

The outermost `SUBSTITUTE` gets rid of any entries which are `no sublist`. Everything so far is wrapped in `ARRAYFORMULA` so that `CONCAT` and `SUBSTITUTE` work properly with ranges instead of single cells.

Finally, each row is joined together with a line break using the outermost `JOIN`.

Functions used:

- [CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en)
- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [CONCAT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast answer, this works well, but how can I disregard blank cells for the main list?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "disregard blank cells"? How do you expect blank cells to appear in your dataset?

Comment: oh, sorry, I am setting a fixed range like A2:A500, to give allowance if there are some additions to the list. As I have tested the formula, it also counted the blank cells making the cell appear like there's a lot of spaces within

Comment: @Mr.YJY I have updated my answer to meet these requirements.